# ImportError: No module named psycopg2

Tags: python, centos, odoo, centos5

In installation process of OpenERP 6, I want to generate a config file with these commands:

```sh
cd /home/openerp/openerp-server/bin/
```

```sh
./openerp-server.py -s --stop-after-init -c /home/openerp/openerp-server.cfg
```

But it always showed the message: `ImportError: No module named psycopg2`

When I checked for psycopg2 package, it's already installed. Package `python-psycopg2-2.4.5-1.rhel5.x86_64` is already installed to its latest version. Nothing to do. What's wrong with this? My server is CentOS, I've installed Python 2.6.7.

Comment: You need to accept some answers on some of your other questions.

Comment: The package installs for python2.4. If you have manually installed 2.6 then you also have to install all the other packages for 2.6.

Comment: Please execute the following command to confirm the python system path. `$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'`

Comment: Will you please try to `import psycopg2` on the python console?

Comment: If you got the answer then select the answer.

Comment: `pip install psycopg2`

Comment: and still hasn't accepted any answer on this question - come on mate,  play the game!

Answer (score 202):

Step 1: Install the dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-dep python-psycopg2
```

Step 2: Run this command in your virtualenv

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Ref: [Fernando Munoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1975004/fernando-munoz)

Comment: This saved me! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169939/python-manage-py-syncdb-fails-with-improperlyconfigured-no-module-named-psyco

Comment: I had to run `easy_install psycopg2`, but your question led me there!

Comment: I found I also had to ```sudo apt-get install libpq-dev```, as I don't have Postgresql installed on the machine I'm trying to install ```psycopg2``` on.

Comment: On arch linux its the same package-name: `pacman -S python-psycopg2`

Comment: For Python3 users: install `libpq-dev postgresql`

Comment: On Kubuntu 16.04 `build-dep` option doesn't work but `sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2` works

Comment: in ubuntu 16.04 it shows E: Unable to locate package build-dep

Comment: You can't use install and build-dep in the same command. They're both commands for apt-get. Should be `sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2`

Comment: Thank you all. Issued fixed. @FernanadoMunoz, how did you determine to run "Step 2: Run this command in your virtualenv
```pip install psycopg2-binary``` " ? Your Step 2 solved my problem. I will appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 105):

Use [psycopg2-binary](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/) instead of [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/).

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Or you will get the warning below:

> UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi.

Reference: [Psycopg 2.7.4 released | Psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2018/02/08/psycopg-274-released/)

Comment: Just FYI - "If you are the maintainer of a published package depending on psycopg2 you shouldn’t use psycopg2-binary as a module dependency" see: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#psycopg-vs-psycopg-binary

Answer (score 67):

I faced the same issue and resolved it with following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: This fixed the error message `You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y ...` that I got after running `sudo apt-get install build-dep python-psycopg2` (even thought I have postgresql installed already).

Answer (score 25):

Try installing

> psycopg2-binary

with
`pip install psycopg2-binary --user`

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me with `python 3.7.3` and `django 3.0.2`

Comment: what is --user for?

Comment: @MuhammadInaamMunir `--user : Install to the Python user install directory for your platform. Typically ~/.local/, or %APPDATA%\Python on Windows.` You can check more info using `pip install --help`.

Answer (score 16):

**Import Error on Mac OS**

 
If `psycopg2` is getting installed but you are unable to import it in your `.py` file then the problem is `libpq`, its linkages, and the library `openssl`, on which `libpq` depends upon. The overall steps are reproduced below. You can check it step by step to know which is the source of error for you and then you can troubleshoot from there.

- Check for the installation of the `openssl` and make sure it's working.
- **Check for installation of `libpq` in your system it may not have been installed or not linked. If not installed then install it using the command `brew install libpq`. This installs libpq library.** [As per the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq.html)

> libpq is the C application programmer's interface to PostgreSQL. libpq is a set of library functions that allow client programs to pass queries to the PostgreSQL backend server and to receive the results of these queries.

- Link libpq using `brew link libpq`, if this doesn't work then use the command: `brew link libpq --force`.
- Also put in your `.zshrc` file the following 
   **`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"`**. This creates all the necessary linkages for `libpq` library .
- Now restart the terminal or use the following command `source ~/.zshrc`.
- Now use the command `pip install psycopg2`. It will work.
  This works, even when you are working in conda environment.
  **N.B. `pip install psycopg2-binary`should be avoided because [as per the developers of the psycopg2 library](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1283)**

> The use of the -binary packages in production is discouraged because in the past they proved unreliable in multithread environments. This might have been fixed in more recent versions but I have never managed to reproduce the failure.

Comment: This solved my problem! psycopg2 was clearly installed because i could successfully connect to my db, but when I tried to run a streamlit app that needed the results from the connection, i got the import not found statement.  This solved it completely.  Thank you!

Comment: This! This is the answer! :)

Answer (score 15):

Please try to run the command `import psycopg2` on the python console. If you get the error then check the `sys.path` where the python look for the install module. If the parent directory of the `python-psycopg2-2.4.5-1.rhel5.x86_64` is there in the `sys.path` or not. If its not in the `sys.path` then run `export PYTHONPATH=<parent directory of python-psycopg2-2.4.5-1.rhel5.x86_64>` before running the openerp server.

Answer (score 13):

Try with these:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 test_env
source test_env/bin/activate
pip install psycopg2
```

run python and try to import if you insist on installing it on your systems python try:

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 7):

Recently faced this issue on my production server. I had installed pyscopg2 using

```
sudo pip install psycopg2
```

It worked beautifully on my local, but had me for a run on my ec2 server.

```
sudo python -m pip install psycopg2
```

The above command worked for me there. Posting here just in case it would help someone in future.

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 5):

i have the same problem, but this piece of snippet alone solved my problem.

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 5):

For python3 on ubuntu, this worked for me:

```
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
$sudo pip3 install psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the `psycopg2` module.

On CentOS:
Make sure Python 2.7+ is installed. If not, follow these instructions: http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/

```
# Python 2.7.6:
$ wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
$ tar xf Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
$ cd Python-2.7.6
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
$ make && make altinstall
$ yum install postgresql-libs

# First get the setup script for Setuptools:
$ wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py

# Then install it for Python 2.7 and/or Python 3.3:
$ python2.7 ez_setup.py

$ easy_install-2.7 psycopg2
```

Even though this is a CentOS question, here are the instructions for Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip python-distribute python-dev
$ easy_install psycopg2
```

Cite: http://initd.org/psycopg/install/

Comment: Hmm getting `ez_setup.py is deprecated and when using it setuptools will be pinned to 33.1.1`

Answer (score 4):

Run into the same issue when I switch to Ubuntu from Windows 10.. the following worked for me.. this after googling and trying numerous suggestions for 2 hours...

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

then

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

I hope this helps someone who has encountered the same problem especially when switching for windows OS to Linux(Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

I have done 2 things to solve this issue:

1. use Python 3.6 instead of 3.8.
2. change Django version to 2.2 (may be working with some higher but I change to 2.2)

Answer (score 1):

For Python3

Step 1: Install Dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python-dev python3-dev
```

Step 2: Install

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 1):

check correctly if you had ON your virtual env of your peoject, if it's OFF then make it ON. execute following cammands:

```
workon <your_env_name>
python manage.py runserver
```

It's working for me

Answer (score 1):

Python2 **importerror no module named psycopg2**

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

> Requirement already satisfied...

Solved by following steps:

```
sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
sudo python -m pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, not sure why nobody mentioned this for mac before.

```
brew install postgresql

pip3 install psycopg2
```

In simple terms, psycopg2 wants us to install postgres first.

PS: Don't forget to upvote, so that it can help other people as well.

Answer (score 1):

For Python3 use this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-psycopg2
```

Comment: This one should be the correct answer i think, work for me on ubuntu 22

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue with below solution :

1. Basically the issue due to _bz2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so Linux package file. Try to find the the location.
2. Check the install python location ( which python3)- Example: /usr/local/bin/python3
3. copy the file under INSTALL_LOCATION/lib/python3.6

```
cp -rvp /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python3.6
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
pip install psycopg2 --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install psycopg-binary
```

The line above helped me

Comment: I don't see how this adds anything not mentioned already back in 2013. Also, the question is about psycopg2, not psycopg.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just follow this link
that contain `$ pip install psycopg2-binary`
its solve my problem in mac m1

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34932534)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go into system environment variable and check if have any script or python file install C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts' if yes then go to system variable and enter this path i hope this can work for you...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).