# python manage.py syncdb fails with "ImproperlyConfigured: No module named 'psycopg2'

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ubuntu

I am currently going through [these steps](http://goo.gl/0Dw0ZQ) to install my first Digital Ocean server, with Ubuntu 14 x32 and Django 1.7, using Python 3.4. I'm new to both Ubuntu and Digitial Ocean, although I developed on Unix years ago.

I'm having a problem with Postgres and Django, when running `syncdb`.

---

(Note: I've installed my virtualenv with `-p /usr/bin/python3.4`, which is different than instructed. I don't know if this makes a difference.)

---

In step 8 it says to install `psycopg2` with

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Which, as described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507320/starting-with-ubuntu-in-digitalocean-pip-failing-with-permission-denied), has to be changed to

```
sudo /home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/bin/pip install psycopg2
```

But it fails with

```
./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

Full output:

```
(django_test_venv)jeffy@originaldjangster:~/django_files/django_test_venv/bin$ sudo /home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/bin/pip install psycopg2
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.5.3.tar.gz (690kB): 690kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/build/psycopg2/setup.py) egg_info for package psycopg2

Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2
    Skipping implicit fixer: buffer
    Skipping implicit fixer: idioms
    Skipping implicit fixer: set_literal
    Skipping implicit fixer: ws_comma
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.3 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090304 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/include/python3.4m -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:0:
    ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/build/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-jilc5e_m-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/include/site/python3.4:
    running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-i686-3.4
creating build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2
copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2
copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2
copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2
copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2
copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2
copying lib/psycopg1.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2
copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2
copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2
copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2
creating build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_dates.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_lobject.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_extras_dictcursor.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_transaction.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_green.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_bug_gc.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_bugX000.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_notify.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/dbapi20_tpc.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_types_basic.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/testconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_with.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_quote.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_copy.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_module.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_types_extras.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_connection.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_async.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_cursor.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/testutils.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
copying tests/test_cancel.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg2/tests
Skipping implicit fixer: buffer
Skipping implicit fixer: idioms
Skipping implicit fixer: set_literal
Skipping implicit fixer: ws_comma
running build_ext
building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.4
creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.3 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090304 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/include/python3.4m -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:0:
./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/build/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-jilc5e_m-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/include/site/python3.4 failed with error code 1 in /home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/build/psycopg2
Storing debug log for failure in /home/jeffy/.pip/pip.log
```

I finally settled on this, which worked:

```
sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
```

It then says to configure the Django `DATABASE` variable, in `settings.py`, to

```
"'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',"
```

and then run

```
python manange.py syncdb
```

`syncdb` is failing with

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'`

Full output:

```
(django_test_venv)jeffy@originaldjangster:~/django_files/django_test$ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 23, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 197, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 40, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 125, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 300, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 166, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 242, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 108, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
(django_test_venv)jeffy@originaldjangster:~/django_files/django_test$
```

I confirmed that this file exists, which matches the `DATABASE` value:

`/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2`

(To repeat myself: I installed my virtualenv with `-p /usr/bin/python3.4`, which is different than instructed, although I don't know if this makes a difference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12928164/2736496), I attempted to import both `psycopg2` and then `postgresql_psycopg2` in IPython. Both returned an `ImportError`.

I saw the `PYTHONPATH` was empty, so I set it to the above directory

```
(django_test_venv)jeffy@originaldjangster:~/django_files/django_test$ echo $PYTHONPATH

(django_test_venv)jeffy@originaldjangster:~/django_files/django_test$ export PYTHONPATH=/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

But again, both packages resulted in an `ImportError` in IPython. As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23104715/2736496) (same question), I ran

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2
```

(Trying `syncdb` here failed the same way.)

and then ([adjusted as required](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507320/starting-with-ubuntu-in-digitalocean-pip-failing-with-permission-denied), which is mentioned in the question-post)

```
sudo /home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/bin/pip install psycopg2
```

And now

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

works.

Answer (score 6):

Install python3x-dev and libpq-dev in your system before install psycopg2 in your virtualenv.

```
apt-get install python3.4-dev libpq-dev
```

then in your virtualenv

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is necessary? Does this mean I'm using a non-release version of Python?

Comment: The *-dev packages contain the files necessary to compile an application from source that uses the functions provided by the library (as psycopg2 uses the libpq and python libraries, among others)

Comment: I was running `sudo pip install psycopg2`  (bad habit?). There were no errors, but `pip freeze` wasn't showing it had installed.  I switched to `pip install psycopg2` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Old topic but could be useful to someone, just had the same issue : postgres with no psycopg2 using python 3.x

Had the same issue, after a bit of digging, this solved my problem :

https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```