# Invalid Connection string in postgresql with superset

Tags: postgresql, connection, apache-superset

I am facing problem to connect postgresql with superset while i giving my connection username,password hostname and database name
and when we click on test connection even I have install postgresql and psycopg2.

It says

> ERROR: {"error": "Connection failed!

The error and shows pop up in the superset page.

```
ERROR: {"error": "Connection failed!

The error message returned was:
No module named 'psycopg2'", "stacktrace": "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/home/tutree/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset/views/core.py\", line 1702, in testconn
    engine = database.get_sqla_engine(user_name=username)
  File \"/home/tutree/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset/utils/core.py\", line 131, in __call__
    value = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File \"/home/tutree/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset/models/core.py\", line 911, in get_sqla_engine
    return create_engine(url, **params)
  File \"/home/tutree/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py\", line 479, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File \"/home/tutree/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py\", line 87, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File \"/home/tutree/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py\", line 737, in dbapi
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
"}
```

Comment: We need more information to solve this problem, can you share the server log output on pastebin?

Comment: i have uploaded an image also.you can check it.

Comment: the error message says: no module found psychopg2, it looks like this is just a duplicate of this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906351/importerror-no-module-named-psycopg2

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by running this command

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message:

The problem may be that you need to install psychopg2 on the same virtualenv as the original superset.

so:

```
1. source your-virtual-env
2. pip install the requriements
3. run superset
```