# Python3 (version 3.6.8) code unable to locate psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm using Centos 7. I installed pyscopg2 successfully (pip3 install psycopg2)

But when I try to import psycopg2 I get the following message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

Comment: Are you sure that your default Python is the same as what `pip3` points to? If you want to be certain it installs, use `python -m pip install psycopg2`

Comment: And how are you running Python?

Comment: this might help to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906351/importerror-no-module-named-psycopg2

Comment: If you had to run `pip3`, it's likely `python` is still Python 2.

Comment: @JammyDodger thanks for pointing it out. I changed default version of python from 2 to 3 and it solved the issue.