# Running python/python3 manage.py runserver inside a venv responds with "wrong architecture" error

Tags: python, django, psycopg2

I spent about all day yesterday attempting to troubleshoot this issue, I've done everything from reinstalling Django, pipenv, etc to changing the Rosetta settings in my terminal. Below is what my terminal responds with after running the command in the venv. I have classmates that are also running on a M1 chip and aren't having this issue. I have psycopg2 installed as well and have verified it is by using the pip list command. This is my first post on Stackoverflow so I apologize for any inconsistencies or formatting.

```html
((django-env) ) bash-3.2$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 115, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 300, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 207, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 204, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 29, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: dlopen(/Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/stevenlopez/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-env-KW2l6c6v/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this applies to your architecture, but have you tried

```sh
pip uninstall psycopg2
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Source: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1216

You might also try the following:

```sh
pip3 install psycopg2
# or
pip3 install psycopg2-binary
```

Source: [ImportError: No module named psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906351/importerror-no-module-named-psycopg2)

Give this a try:

```sh
brew install libpq
```

Then try the above.

Comment: I have tried this. The new error it throws me is saying that 'No module named psycopg2'.

Comment: Do you have Postgresql installed?  If not, do `brew install postgresql`, and then the above.

Comment: I do have postgresql installed! I've managed to use postgresql in previous projects with no problem, it seems to just be an issue now that I am trying to use it with Django.

Comment: I've edited my answer, but sorry, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: All good! I appreciate the help tho man. Thank you.